# Click not always triggered on buttons close to the right side of a web page on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

We have a design with buttons on the right side of our webpage. (close button in top-right corner of a fullscreen popup, FAB in bottom-right)

On touch devices, it feels like the buttons on the right side don't always work, 
even if we use a touchscreen pen instead of a finger to be sure we click on it. 
(The buttons are large enough: 48 CSS pixels)

After some investigation it looks like a small region on the right side of the page don't fire click events. (like the location were the scrollbar can appear on the page)

I only see the problem on iOS, not on Android

CodePen Sample: http://codepen.io/jovdb/full/MybojG (make sure to test it on iOS device)

I tried different ways to right align:

```
<div style='text-align: right'>
  <a href="#">A</a>
</div>
```

- float: right;
- text-align: right;
- position: absolute; right: 0;
- flexbox

EDITED: depends on orientation:

- iPad 2: iOS: 7.0.4; Safari 7, WebKit v537.51.1

  - 2 orientations work: (home button on bottom and at the right side)
- iPhone 6: iOS: 9.2.1; Safari 9.0, WebKit v601.1.46

  - all orientations don't work
- iPhone 6: iOS: 9.2.1; Chrome 48, WebKit v601.1

  - all orientations don't work
- iPhone 4: iOS: 7.1.2; Safari 7, Webkit v537.51.2

  - only OK when home button is at the right

I don't think it is a physical limitation by the device because buttons close to the left side of the screen work in all orientations.

Does anybody else has this problem?

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: I tried this at home on my iPad (iOS 8.2), in all 4 orientations, and amazingly, in one landscape orientation tapping on your buttons near the right-edge works! This feels like a bug? Might be related to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5557721?start=0&tstart=0)?

Comment: Indeed I also noticed on iPad: 2 sides don't work (home button on top and home button at left side)